Caracteres especiales en Supabase Auth
Estoy necesitando registrar un mail en Supabase Auth, el problema que estoy teniendo es que contiene "ñ". Estoy buscando información sobre la codificación que se utiliza o si es configurable y no encuentro nada.

Cualquier información se agradece

Eso más bien parece una pregunta para soporte...
